# Autoscrolling in ArcGIS Geoprocessing Results window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, background-geoprocessing, results-window

When checking the results window for messages while doing a lot of background processing it's rather annoying to scroll to the current message. So i was wondering if there is a trick to directly scroll to the current message line or is there such a feature in newer (>10.2) versions of ArcGIS?

Comment: You ask about "newer versions of ArcGIS" but what version are you using?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by scrolling to the current message. Can you please post a picture of what it looks like?

Comment: While messages keep popping up in  the Results window its scrollbar stays in the same position and can only be moved to the current message manually. By current message i mean the most recent arcpy.AddMessage of a running script. So when i check on a script that runs for several hours und outputs a lot of (crucial) messages I dont want to scroll to the current message. Sorry for beeing unclear I thought the title is moreless self explanatory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the script/tool in background mode, the Results window won't scroll to the latest message. This is not implemented in ArcGIS Desktop up to version 10.6, and it most likely won't be available in the upcoming versions.

Your only options are:

1. To use the foreground processing in ArcMap where the tool dialog window will be auto-scrolled to the latest message.
2. Use ArcGIS Pro where only background processing is enabled and the log auto-scrolls to the latest message.

Demo from Pro tool (with the messages being printed):

```
for i in range(15):
    time.sleep(1)
    arcpy.AddMessage(i)
```

The recording:

[image]

Comment: Foreground processing isn't an option since i use 64 bit background processing (these options are related, aren't they?). So i assume it's play with what you got. But thank you for your elaborate answer!

Comment: @maxwhere, you are right, if you run a tool with 64bit background processing you won't be able to run them in foreground. Keep in mind that you could migrate to Pro at some point.